# emacs and dictionary.el

Tags: emacs, dictionary

I installed emacs 24.1 and dictionary.el, which is a dictd client plugin for emacs. I am able to look up dictionary within command "dict xxx", it works just fine.
However, dictionary.el doesn't work correctly, whenever I use "M-x dictionary-search" to find something, minibuffer displays "dictionary-mode: Symbol's function definition is void: make-local-hook".

Here is what I have in dot-emacs:
    (setq dictionary-server "localhost")
Any ideas?

Comment: My guess is that it needs an update for Emacs 24.  My Emacs 23 has `make-local-hook` but it is marked as obsolete since 21.1, so I guess they removed it in Emacs 24.

Comment: yeah, I've done lots of search on internet, lots of article said so, too. Does this mean dictionary.el has some kind of reference to make-local-hook?

Comment: Link to dictionary.el please.

Comment: you can find it [here](http://me.in-berlin.de/~myrkr/dictionary/index.html). I use gentoo, so I install it directly from gentoo repo.

Comment: Yes, there is a known bug in `dictionary.el` for which Debian has a patch, according to http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DictMode (scroll down to near the end).

Comment: Thank you, tripleee. That's the information I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to http://me.in-berlin.de/~myrkr/dictionary/

Then the issue would be here:

```el
(make-local-hook 'kill-buffer-hook)
(add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook 'dictionary-close t t)
```

Because the `add-hook` call supplies the `local` argument, you can resolve this issue by deleting (or commenting out) the first line with the call to `make-local-hook`. That line was only left in the code to provide backward-compatibility with very old versions of Emacs, and is otherwise redundant.

Make sure you send them a bug report.

**Edit**: tripleee has pointed out that this problem has already been fixed in the current version of the library, which now lives at the following URL:

https://github.com/myrkr/dictionary-el

Comment: hi, phils.   `(make-local-hook 'kill-buffer-hook)` will eval failed. seems like Emacs 24 doesn't have a function named that.

Comment: No need to send a bug report; it's already fixed in the upstream Git.  (The URL you link to regrettably doesn't have a pointer to the new location; it's at https://github.com/myrkr/dictionary-el now.)

Comment: Thanks tripleee. hero2008: Yes indeed -- it's been obsolete for years, and was removed in Emacs 24. I was saying that you could fix the problem by *removing* that line from the code. (But as tripleee has pointed out an up-to-date version of the library, you can just use that instead.)

Comment: Thanks phils, I'm sorry that havn't reading your answer carefully :P

Answer (score 0):

"localhost" is defined in `/etc/dictd/dict.conf`.  It should be OK to remove or comment out the setq.  By default, dictionary-el points to dict.org.

Comment: no matter I set dictionary-server to "localhost" or its original value "dict.org", emacs shows the same message.